# Pandas to take portions of data-frame and normalize values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization

A data-frame of two columns as below.

I want to pick the portion by giving a date, and normalize (by using min-max method) the "Weight".

Here is how I plan:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'Date': ["2000-02-01", "2000-03-01", "2000-04-03", "2000-05-01", "2000-06-01", "2000-07-03", "2000-08-01", "2000-09-01", "2000-10-02", "2000-11-01"], 
'Weight' : [478, 26, 144, 9, 453, 24, 383, 314, 291, 286]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_1 = df.loc[df['Date'] >= "2000-04-01"]

df_1 = (df_1 - df_1.min()) / (df_1.max() - df_1.min())

print df_1

# the ideal output is two columns: 1 for Dates after "2000-04-01". 1 for their correspondent normalized "Weights".
```

It gives error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

How can I achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: dates are strings, you should convert them to `datetime` objects first using. `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` look-up other questions to find more about converting

Comment: what is the logic you are using for 'normalizing'? it is not clear to me. do you expect the column `Weight` to be same after a particular output? IF you paste your expected output, that would be much useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert values to datetimes, then processing only `Weight` column and overwrite column `Weight`:

```
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] )
df_1 = df.loc[df['Date'] >= "2000-04-01"]

a = (df_1['Weight'] - df_1['Weight'].min()) / (df_1['Weight'].max() - df_1['Weight'].min())

print (df_1.assign(Weight = a))
        Date    Weight
2 2000-04-03  0.304054
3 2000-05-01  0.000000
4 2000-06-01  1.000000
5 2000-07-03  0.033784
6 2000-08-01  0.842342
7 2000-09-01  0.686937
8 2000-10-02  0.635135
9 2000-11-01  0.623874
```

Comment: good day, sir! thank you for the knowledge sharing and the help!

Answer (score 2):

data type of date column is string.so you have to change it to.for that you can use this approach==>

`df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`